# Django Channels: delayed group message

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm writing multiplayer online browser game and have some trouble now

My consumer:

```
@channel_session
def tankAction(message):
    user = message.channel_session.session_key
    room = message.channel_session['room']
    data = json.loads(rdb.get('battle-'+room))
    recieve_data = json.loads(message.content['text'])

    if recieve_data['action'] == 'tankDestroyed':
        for tank in data['tanks']:
            if tank['id'] != recieve_data['data']:
                tank['score'] += 1

        Group('battle-%s' % room).send({
            'text': json.dumps({
                'action': 'setScore',
                'tanks': data['tanks']
            })
        })

        data = json.dumps(data)
        rdb.set('battle-' + room, data)

        p = Process(target=startGame, args=(room, ))
        p.start()
```

and function:

```
def startGame(room):
    sleep(3)
    Group('battle-%s' % room).send({
            'text': json.dumps({
                'action': 'respawn',
            })
    })
    print ('battle-%s' % room +' respawn')
```

But there isn't any message from server on client-side. 
With Django Channels.delay i don't know how to release it. I've combined in one consumer message.send and group.send - all work fine, but this thing doesn't want to do it.

Comment: what is the reasoning behind adding `multiprocessing` to this?

Comment: first idea that come. I'm new it this. Do you have other implementation?

Comment: What is the goal here?

Comment: start game after server signal

Comment: So why are you sleeping for 3 seconds?

Comment: on client side i start countdown for 3 seconds, server will start the game after this time. Online could be 6 players. One signal to start countdown, second - start the game

Comment: you should do this a different way. One way to do it would be to maybe do a counter or something and do an `if counter == 6: Group(x).send(y)`.